# QAF | Desired capabilities not working with QAF 4.0.0RC1 & Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, qaf

Desired capabilities are not working after upgrade to QAF 4.0.0RC1 with Selenium 4. I have tried below properties:

```
chrome.additional.capabilities​​={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless=new","--window-size=3000,1080"]}}
driver.additional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless=new","--window-size=1920,1080"]}
chrome.additional.capabilities​​={"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless=new","--window-size=3000,1080"]}}
driver.additional.capabilities={"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless=new","--window-size=1920,1080"]}
```

I have referred below link and the desired capabilities are working for QAF 3.0.1 with Selenium 3.
https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.15/setting_driver_capabilities.html

Chrome to accept the capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely because of [known bug](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/issues/444). It has been fixed and should be available in next release. You can try 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ to make sure that issue is because of that bug.

Comment: Hi @user861594, How do I get access to the snapshot?

Comment: you need to add snapshot repository entry in dependency management file (in pom.xml if using maven, ivy.xml if using ivy). BTW 4.0.0-RC2 is released and available in maven central repository.